# Specify item fields to Load using SharePoint 2010 Client OM

Tags: list, client-object-model

How can I dynamically generate/specify a list of item fields I want to load when querying a list using the Client OM?

This is possible to do using the tag on the CAML query, but this loads additional unwanted fields, making the payload bigger. See here: [blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/11/01/using-the-sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-part-3.aspx)

Here's the testing code im using:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://myserver/sites/mysite");
Web site = clientContext.Web;

List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList");
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.Load(listItems,
      items => items.ListItemCollectionPosition,
      items => items.Include(
              item => item["ID"],
              item => item["Title"]
              ));

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

What I want to do is to generate the lambda expression's for the Include method at runtime. Still no luck. Every solution I try gives me error

> "The query expression is not supported."

Comment: Could you create a lambda expression for include dynamically? I need the same. Thanks,
Manvir

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution I found was to import the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` namespace.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
```

If the using for the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` namespace without the alias not is in the list you get the error as you mentiont in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found its resolution. Use LoadQuery instead of Load. Pls see complete solution here
http://www.manvir.net/invalidqueryexpressionexception-the-query-expression-is-not-supported/

Comment: Its is best practice here to put some piece of code or information along with the reference/source link, and not just providing urls, some ppl might have other sites blocked, so its better they can read the stuffs here itself